# PerformancePoint 2013 Timing Out

Tags: 2013, performancepoint

Anyone else having an issue with PerformancePoint 2013 timing out when querying a cube? The strange thing is that it works in PP 2007.

Comment: more information required....check this one may help u http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jorg_klein/archive/2009/02/06/ssas-speed-up-dimensions-using-a-null-default-cube-measure.aspx

Comment: also try to increase the time-out value in the datasource. "value Set the duration of no response before a data source query is canceled"http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsto/ee620542(v=office.12)

Comment: Thanks for the links. I will re-examine the query, but like I said, the query works in our PerformancePoint 2007 environment. I do have the data source query time out set to 3600 seconds which is the maximum allowable. I also have made all the changes recommended in the following blog: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3e676663-0d5f-4cbf-9694-14e82772c8e6/unable-to-create-report-query-produced-too-many-results?forum=ppsmonitoringandanalytics

Comment: From the ULS logs:  A PerformancePoint service application call was aborted by the caller.  This may indicate the HttpRuntime executionTimeout for the Web Application is configured to a value smaller than the DataSourceQueryTimeout for the PerformancePoint Service Application.

Comment: may be, you can try to change the setting...you can via web.config of web application(on all servers)

Comment: I have also increased the http execution timeout from 360 to 3600 in the web config.

Comment: I have also increased the http execution timeout from 360 to 3600 in the web config -- on both my servers. My environment is virtualized and I have 20 GB RAM allotted to it which is the maximum I can get.